# javascript apply style to selected element based on Id and class

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript, and I was wondering how I could style the particular HTML, which looks like the following:

```
<a id="234" action="." class="rawup"</a>
<a id="234" action="." class="rawdown"></a>
```

What I am looking to apply styles to the above such as:

```
document.getElementById("234").style.backgroundPosition='0px 150px';
```

which works fine..but, what I would like to do is getElementById and then by getElementByClass (?) so that I can distinguish between classes "rawup" and "rawdown". So, something like:

```
document.getElementById("234").getElementByClass("rawup").style.backgroundPosition='0px 150px';
```

I tried the above and it does not seem to work -was wondering if someone could guide me on this. Sorry total JS newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

First: You *cannot* have more than one element with the same [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). That's why we call them *identifiers*. It's invalid (and nonsensical) to use the same `id` value on more than one element.

But answering the question of how you do a query for both `id` and `class`, you *can* do that on [a browser that supports `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector). But not if the `id` starts with a digit, because `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` use CSS selectors, and `id` values starting with digits are invalid in CSS (they're valid in HTML).

If we assume you want to find an element with the `id` `"abc"` and the class `"foo"`, but you don't want to find the `"abc"` element if it doesn't have the class `"foo"`, you could do this:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#abc.foo");
if (element) {
    // Found it
}
else {
    // Didn't find it
}
```

But again, don't use that to differentiate between two elements with the `id` `"abc"`, because you must not give the same `id` to more than one element.

Comment: Crowder: Thanks for your explanation. I will come up with better ids.